# Construct a continuous onto map from $(0,1]$ to $[0,1]$

Tags: functions

What are some example of continuous surjective function in a given interval from $(0,1]$ to $[0,1]$? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I really suggest you think about this yourself, it is an interesting problem at first. If you have, then tell us what you have thought in the question. That way, your question will receive  a good  response. Also, look out for duplicates, like the one above

Comment: Try playing with $\sin$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this function:-
$$f:(0,1]\to[0,1], f(x)=\sin(\pi x)$$
$f(0.5)=1$ and $f(1)=0$. Since $f(x)$ is continuos, it acquires all intermediate values by Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

Function does not have to be bijective or monotonic.

So construct something (continuous) that maps $[0.5,1]$ to $[0,1]$, and make sure that $(0, 0.5)$ also stay in the range.